# How do I get the date difference as a floating-point number with millisecond precision

Tags: java, date, date-difference

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    long sTime =  new Date().getTime();
    Thread.sleep(3234);
    long eTime =  new Date().getTime();
    float diff = ((eTime-sTime)/1000);
    System.out.println(diff);
}
```

In the above code, I am expecting the output to be 3.234 but it is 3.0. I want the exact difference between two times in seconds, with a fractional part.

Comment: long (int) division. If you want more precision use nanoTime()

Comment: Not that `sleep` is *not* guaranteed to sleep for precisely the duration you give it, so even when you fix your program, you will find that it does not output 3.234. It will probably be coarser than milliseconds precision, and sometimes the duration will be noticeably longer.

Comment: Note that using a `float` or even a `double` is incompatible with your requirement for _the exact difference_ due to the [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) or floating point numbers. You may want to consider using a `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing an integral division instead of a floating-point one. Try this:

```
float diff = ((float)(eTime-sTime)/1000.0);
```

As you are using `long`s, I further suggest you to use `double` datatype for greater precision:

```
double diff = ((double)(eTime-sTime)/1000.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    double sTime =  new Date().getTime();
    Thread.sleep(3234);
    double eTime =  new Date().getTime();
    double diff = ((eTime-sTime)/1000);
    System.out.println(diff);
```